# Is there an alternative migrations workflow for very early stages of development. Laravel

Tags: laravel, database-migration

**My reasoning, you can skip to below if not interested**

I understand how the general procedure of migrations work and the purpose they serve, and very happy to use them in the way that is expected, that is by adding and removing fields as nessesary throughout the applications life.

My query is that at the very beginning of a project I rarely know many of the fields I will need in a given table, and at the very early stages of my projects I want to get the main features and relationships set up, and maybe just use some dud fields before the client makes up their minds on things.

The bottom line is it hurts my OCD knowing there are extra migration files sitting there that potentially look nothing like v1.0 of the project... once im at v0.5 I may decide im far enough along to start properly managing migrations.

**Thats my thoughts, but here is the question:**

What is the cleanest steps to reuse the same migration script again and again in the early stages of a project while there is no worry about loss of data or rolling back.

Just to add to this i would not want to refresh the entire migration because I would really prefer to keep any data I am playing around and especially the user table for staying logged in to the backend etc.

**Would it be wrong to do this:**

Could I just remove the migration row in the table, then run the migration?

This feels like it would have side effects, and possibly screw up rolling back, is that the case? What part does the migration table play, as this seems to work in practice?

**Final words**

Please bear in mind this is just a concept I'm trying to get my head around. If its absolutely bad practice no matter the circumstance I can accept it!

Comment: Personally I modify the migration file until it reaches the point where I want it to be before releasing. You can just use `php artisan migrate:fresh` to run all migrations from scratch. However once released then migrations that already ran in production must not be modified

Comment: Nice, in reality I would want to do it like that up until release too :) doing "migrate:fresh" though loses all the rows as far as Im aware, when sometimes all i want to do is add a single field so seems a little overkill if you know what I mean.

Comment: You could write a [seeder](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/seeding) to populate your DB with test data to work with and then using `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

Create a new seeder with `php artisan make:seeder UserSeeder`

Edit the seeder to "seed" the necessary data. Ex:

```
DB::table('users')->insert([
    'name' => 'John Doe',
    'email' => 'johndoe@example.com',
    'password' => Hash::make('password'),
]);
```

Then call the built-in artisan function `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` which will drop all tables and re-run all of your migrations, then seed your data with your seeders.

You can read more about this process [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/seeding).

**Original:**

If you plan to support a live application in the long run, chances are you will have very many of these separate migration files that will still hurt your OCD every time you make a new one. It happens to me every time I create a new one migration to alter a table, haha.

However, in development I can understand your point if you're working on a private codebase and no other developers will be trying to keep up with your changes. If you do, any changes you make to the old migration files will be very tough for them to mimic as the migrations table keeps track of what migrations need to be run (if any), so if someone else tried to migrate after you've changed a previous migration, nothing would happen.

What I would do, is either set up a database seeder in Laravel so you can quickly reseed the data in the table if you rollback a migration, or get a sql dump of your table and reinsert it after you've migrated again.

Another thing you could consider is, not to worry about the migrations directory at this point in development and once you're ready to deploy or push, go through your table alterations and kind of "refactor" them into your desired migrations. But definitely run some thorough testing after this to ensure you're not missing any columns or alterations.

Comment: I have just looked into seeding and it does exactly what I need! If you could give the quick steps in your answer including creating a simple seeder and running "php artisan migrate:fresh --seed". That is definitely the way I'm going to work going forward :) OCD issues are solved! I personally have created a single seeder and am using that to insert a couple of users, an author that is associated with that user etc. But it can all be re run with that one command. Pretty happy right now

Comment: @Zephni Perfect! I'm glad that it lead you to something that worked for you! I've edited my answer to describe the specific workflow as you requested.